# Getting localhost for next page url in production

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets, django-pagination

hlo, I have deployed a Django rest app in production. When I call a list API there is a pagination, and I am getting localhost for next page URL.

I am using GenericViewSet and LimitOffsetPagination for pagination. My app is running in docker container.And it is pointed to a specific domain. We can access it using domain name "https://abc.xyz.com". But I have used `python manage.py runserver:0.0.0.0:8000`(it's just for testing) CMD for running the server.
[Here is the image for more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWS0a.png).
I am calling an live hosted API to get a list from postman. In response data list contains pagination, which contains "http://localhost:8000/api/transaction/?limit=10&offset=10&ordering=-pk&purpose=1". for next page link instead of domain name.

I have hosted application using docker. Following is my docker file:

```
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app
# Copy requirements file
COPY requirements.txt .
# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
# Copy project files
COPY . .
# Collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
# Run migrations
RUN python manage.py makemigrations
RUN python manage.py migrate
# Expose the port 8000
EXPOSE 8000
# Start the server
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

What should I do to get "https://abc.xyz.com/api/transaction/" instead of "http://localhost:8000/api/transaction/"

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing and what is your expectation ? Try to explain more detail in your question

Comment: My problem is I am getting "http://localhost:8000/nextpage/?page=2" for next page url in pagination in production. It should be my domain "https://abc.xyz.com/nextpage/?page=2".

Comment: do you use <a> href to set up the link in html ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: did you solve the problem , I have also same problem.

Comment: well, yes I solved the problem by customizing the next/previous page links by overriding the method in pagination class. But I don't think that is the good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative url in your html, something like this:

`http://localhost:8000/nextpage/?page=2`

to

`<a href="/nextpage/?page=2" />`

When you change to this, your url will be change to `yourdomain/nextpage/?page2`. So you can run your app in localhost or VM or in container without changing host or absolute url for one by one environment you set up in project.

Comment: I am using Django REST API.

Comment: I know but you must have html template right ?

Comment: no I do not have html template. I am testing this API using postman. After researching for 3-4 days I understood this is not the problem with my app but with the deployment process. Now I do not know how two solve this deployment problem

Comment: oh i see, i have to go out right now. I will update the answer as soon as i can.